# SwiftUI: TextField placeholder vs title when used in Form

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I am using a TextField with the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var field: String = "Test"

    var body: some View
    {
        Form
        {
            HStack
            {
                TextField("", text: $field)
                    .border(.blue)
            }
            .border(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

My problems that when using the TextField within a form it is introducing some space at the beginning of the text field for a title:

[image]

Sure enough if I change the "" to "Description" it fills in the space with the word Description.

According to what I have read I thought the first parameter of TextField was supposed to be a placeholder?

This seems like a very basic question and I'm embarrassed that I haven't been able to find the answer myself. How do I get rid of the space at the beginning of the TextField?

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2. Is this on macOS? Works fine with macOS 12.1/M1. Provide minimal reproducible example with system specification where do you test it.

Comment: Are you referring to the grey area to the left of the highlighted text field? that is the Form. Aside from that I also don't see any issue on my Machine /Xcode Environment

Comment: yes. I want to eliminate the grey area to the left hand side as that is causing all my forms to go off position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem. It turns out that the Form command is not absolutely necessary like with would be with HTML. When you use it, its purpose appears to be to pad the title column to be the same width so the TextFields align themselves consistently. Removing the Form command puts the behaviour of TextField back to using placeholder and removes the spacing at the front of the TextField.